# iOS tableview cell layout auto constraint, 4 labels per row, 2 on 2 sides, 2 rows

Tags: ios

I cannot think the correct auto constraint for below tableview cell.

Every word is a label. So, that are 4 labels per row, and 2 rows.

[image]

I tried to align "20" to trailing right, but it showed overlap with "name".

Updated after trying some suggestions:

[image]

Comment: Share some Code?

Comment: How is this not a job a job for stack views?

Comment: @matt iOS 9+ ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Is this the case to down vote the question ? He is asking HOW, if his approach is wrong, or not the best, suggest to change. Or just don't answer.  His question is legitime. I can see a distribution of down votes "à gogo" just because certain people don't agree.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to priorize constraints.

I got this result:

[image]

Using this storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="12121" systemVersion="16G29" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="pSd-1g-yzb">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="12089"/>
        <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Second-->
        <scene sceneID="N6t-4u-rEI">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="pSd-1g-yzb" customClass="second" customModule="sdv" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="2V7-Hz-GBP"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="MEu-0g-Ng5"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="JAf-fN-bhN">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="106" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="RxB-gO-BaE">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="104" width="375" height="563"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <prototypes>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="Cell" rowHeight="106" id="ZS4-z5-fDX" customClass="cellTest" customModule="sdv" customModuleProvider="target">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="106"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="ZS4-z5-fDX" id="Gzo-a3-xSX">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="105.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="name:" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="KZg-iQ-1yZ">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="15" width="47" height="21"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="QTh-E8-jrz"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="47" id="pXL-H9-1Pi"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="John" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="UDy-Br-8rJ">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="63" y="15" width="107" height="21"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="A4A-fg-T3O"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="107" id="clg-dt-kRd"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="City:" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Ofl-yu-07n">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="44" width="35" height="21"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="35" id="byF-mE-EzO"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="pEY-1J-Juf"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="HK" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="uvr-jw-AgS">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="63" y="44" width="107" height="21"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="O8S-sI-SVg"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="107" id="OKt-4D-irY"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="20" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="OVW-yq-ra7">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="296" y="15" width="38" height="21"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="38" id="Tve-KR-3qg"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="XY5-8k-a8r"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Country:" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="sY6-0y-uY8">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="222" y="44" width="66" height="21"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="66" id="FQ4-Du-Kg5"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="f2H-DW-ZsP"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="HK" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="yGP-I1-NoG">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="296" y="44" width="38" height="21"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="pE3-ud-vJm"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="38" id="vLT-EO-jKF"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Age:" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="uPL-7i-yNc">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="253" y="15" width="35" height="21"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="35" id="mg8-e4-baN"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="oTV-cD-jy1"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="KZg-iQ-1yZ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Gzo-a3-xSX" secondAttribute="topMargin" constant="7" id="30Z-xf-2jT"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="uvr-jw-AgS" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="UDy-Br-8rJ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="3sf-vl-Ik6"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="Ofl-yu-07n" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Gzo-a3-xSX" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="Cq6-Rx-vkU"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="OVW-yq-ra7" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="33" id="DWV-l5-f18"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="Ofl-yu-07n" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="KZg-iQ-1yZ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="KaQ-NN-tLo"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="yGP-I1-NoG" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="sY6-0y-uY8" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="O2L-ng-7xA"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="UDy-Br-8rJ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Gzo-a3-xSX" secondAttribute="topMargin" constant="7" id="PVB-ck-Dlf"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="yGP-I1-NoG" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="33" id="RXc-0r-9rt"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="uvr-jw-AgS" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Ofl-yu-07n" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="ZQs-MN-PDV"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="KZg-iQ-1yZ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Gzo-a3-xSX" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="ZZJ-gs-0Fs"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="yGP-I1-NoG" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="OVW-yq-ra7" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="f9a-58-K8F"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="sY6-0y-uY8" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="uPL-7i-yNc" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="hWN-Y2-3Ae"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="OVW-yq-ra7" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="uPL-7i-yNc" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="mcM-m5-OXn"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="UDy-Br-8rJ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="KZg-iQ-1yZ" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="oOn-mC-oox"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="OVW-yq-ra7" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Gzo-a3-xSX" secondAttribute="topMargin" constant="7" id="ycQ-u3-6lf"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="uPL-7i-yNc" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Gzo-a3-xSX" secondAttribute="topMargin" constant="7" id="zbm-JK-27a"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </prototypes>
                                <connections>
                                    <outlet property="dataSource" destination="pSd-1g-yzb" id="tb8-8p-FL3"/>
                                    <outlet property="delegate" destination="pSd-1g-yzb" id="plR-Bc-tN0"/>
                                </connections>
                            </tableView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="tableView" destination="RxB-gO-BaE" id="kTb-PN-Tpd"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="skk-yw-pih" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="493.60000000000002" y="74.212893553223395"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

You can create a test project and paste this on your storyboard file. Then you will be able to see how I did the constraints.
To do that, open it as source code:

[image]

Create a class for your cell:

```
class cellTest: UITableViewCell {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
}
```

And use fixed values for your delegate table view:

```
class second: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier: String = "Cell"
        let cell : cellTest = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! cellTest
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

}
```

Just set both classes in your storyboard, for you VC and for your cell, set the reuseIdentifier in attribute inspector, table view datasource and delegate to your VC and run.

Comment: thanks a lot. But when I previewed the app to ipad, that is extra space. e.g. http://i63.tinypic.com/25jwo5v.png

Comment: You have to use Vary for Traits to adjust to iPad

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You should also set one of the labels horizontal Content Compression Resistance Priority to e.g. 700.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried. but still has some issue, I just updated my question, thanks a lto.

Comment: What constraint issues do you have? Can be seen like this: http://imgur.com/a/vsl1n